# Scala Circe - Extending Decoder getting no implicit arguments

Tags: scala, circe

I am still learning scala and attempting to use circe's decoders, but running into a little trouble with a context bound I think. I'm unsure why scala is expecting this implicit argument?

```
 abstract class Input[A](namedDecoder: String) extends Decoder[A]
  abstract class Test[T: Input](args: Int)

  case class InputImpl(hash: String, namedDecoder: String) extends Input(namedDecoder)
  class TestImpl(x: Int) extends Test[InputImpl](x)
```

I'm getting an error: No implicit arguments of type Input[InputImpl] and I'm a little confused what I'm missing here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Circe uses type class approach. Take a look to how this works at https://medium.com/se-notes-by-alexey-novakov/of-scala-type-classes-6647c48e39d9

Comment: You are trying to use a typeclass as subtyping, those are two different approaches to polymorphism. Check this: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Comment: I do see how I'm mixing up two different approaches to polymorphism here.  I want my test's parameter to be a Decoder[A] with a namedDecoder parameter, but I don't see another way to do this other than subtyping or maybe trying something with structural types? I was thinking to add some sort of lower bound:   abstract class Input(namedDecoder: String)  and abstract class Test[T >: Input with Decoder[T]](args: Int) but this doesn't even compile because of a cyclic reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you don't want `Input` to be a `Decoder` but rather have an instance of `Decoder` associated with it.

Check this code:

```scala
abstract class Input[A](namedDecoder: String)
final case class InputImpl(hash: String, namedDecoder: String) extends Input(namedDecoder)

abstract class Test[T <: Input : Decoder](args: Int)
class TestImpl(x: Int) extends Test[InputImpl](x)
```

---

Otherwise, I really don't understand what is that you need to do, but maybe something like this?

```scala
trait Input[A] {
  def decoder: Decoder[A]
  def namedDecoder: String
}
object Input {
  final class InputImpl[A](
      val hash: String,
      override final val namedDecoder: String,
      override final val decoder: Decoder[A]
  ) extends Input[A]
  
  implicit final def fromDecoder[A](implicit ev: Decoder[A]): Input[A] =
    new InputImpl(hash = "someHash", namedDecoder = "someName", decoder = ev)
}

abstract class Test[T: Input](args: Int)
final class TestImpl(x: Int) extends Test[String](x)
```

Although `Input` doesn't feel like a **typeclass**, why do you want to pass it implicitly? From where would things like `hash` and `namedDecoder` even come from? Those feel like just normal parameters.